# Unable to save Unicode (Greek) characters to the file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I encounter a problem with saving Unicode (Greek) characters to the file , the problem is when the write function of the program  reach Greek characters of CString . 
I have no problem to save English characters .

I don’t know where i do wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
void CCheckOmadesOroiDlg::SaveLathoiToFile()
{
CStringW sf;
CStringW str_to_save = L"";


str_to_save = L"Nikitria stili ";

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    sf.Format(L"%d ", exada.vExades[geydomada].number[i]);
    str_to_save += sf;
}

sf = L"\n\n";
str_to_save += sf;
sf.Format(L"Λαθοι Ομαδων απο=%d μεχρι=%d (%d)\n", glathoi.lathoiomadon_apo, glathoi.lathoiomadon_mexri, glathoi.lathoiomadon);
str_to_save += sf;

CString filename; filename.Format(_T("lathoi_%d.txt"), geydomada);
wofstream file(filename, ios::out);
streamsize n = str_to_save.GetLength()*sizeof(WCHAR);
file.write(str_to_save, n);
file.flush();
file.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to write Unicode characters to file.

This is the code.

```
void CCheckOmadesOroiDlg::SaveLathoiToFile()
{
CStringW sf;
CStringW str_to_save = L"";

str_to_save = L"Nikitria stili ";

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    sf.Format(L"%d ", exada.vExades[geydomada].number[i]);
    str_to_save += sf;
}

sf = L"\n\n";
str_to_save += sf;
sf.Format(L"Λαθοι Ομαδων απο=%d μεχρι=%d (%d)\n", glathoi.lathoiomadon_apo, glathoi.lathoiomadon_mexri, glathoi.lathoiomadon);
str_to_save += sf;


wchar_t* bufferwchar = new wchar_t[str_to_save.GetLength()];
bufferwchar = (wchar_t*)str_to_save.GetBuffer();

char filename[50]; sprintf_s(filename, "lathoi_%d.txt", geydomada);
FILE *stream;

// Open file in text mode:
if (fopen_s(&stream, filename, "wt,ccs=UNICODE") == 0)
{

    fwrite(bufferwchar, sizeof(bufferwchar), str_to_save.GetLength()/2, stream);
    fclose(stream);
}
}
```